# Class inheritance: static members and virtual methods

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm making an exception class that simply reports the problem on `cout` and exits the program, like this:

```
class Exception {
protected:
    short code;
    string text;
public:
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Exception& p_exception) {
        return out << p_exception.text;
    }
    void execute() { cout << text; exit(code);
};
```

and it's specific examples:

```
class IndexOutOfBoundsException : public Exception {
public:
    IndexOutOfBoundsException() {
        this->text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to access the index outside the bounds of the array!";
        code = 1;
    }
};
class IndexOfEmptyFieldException : public Exception {
public:
    IndexOfEmptyFieldException() {
        this->text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to access the index of an empty field!";
        code = 2;
    }
};
class AllocationFailureException : public Exception {
public:
    AllocationFailureException() {
        this->text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to allocate dynamic memory!";
        code = 3;
    }
};
```

In my head, it all seemed very neat, but now it somehow doesn't seem like a good OOP example. While I was thinking it over, it came to me that I could somehow use the static members, like making `int code;` a static variable specific to the inheriting classes. Or, I could make method `void generate();` a pure virtual function with `= 0`, which was my first idea.

My question is: *Is it possible to make this solution a better OOP example and/or am I missing the general point of OOD?*

Comment: This probably belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Give your `Exception` class a (possibly `protected`) constructor that receives the values for `text` and `code`. Then call the constructor through the initializer list in the derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, that reduces object footprint and moves memory allocation away from throw clause:

```
class Exception {
protected:
  short code;
  const string &text;
  Exception(short code, const string &text) :
    code(code), text(text)
  {}
...
}

class IndexOutOfBoundsException : public Exception {
private:
  static const string c_text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to access the index outside the bounds of the array!";
public:
  IndexOutOfBoundsException() : Exception(1, c_text)
  { }
};
```